# (JSP2-MVC) How to iterate an arraylist of java bean?

Tags: jsp, for-loop, model-view-controller, iteration

I am looking for a way to iterate over an arraylist of java beans in a jsp2 page.

I have a bean "catalog" with an arraylist of beans "items" and for each bean

I get it with: `${catalog.items};`
I need to display each item as a `<li></li>`.

What is the correct way of doing this iteration in jsp2 MVC project without other older or newer framework, just JSP2 respecting MVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The answer above not respecting MVC

```
<li>---</li>
```

## must be written in the VUE and not in the MODEL(BEAN)

I think you want to display your list in a jsp page using MVC architecture 
the way is :

1/add a function that return a list in your bean (Model)

2/a servlet that instantiate this bean and call this function and set this list in request (controller)

3/the jsp page desplay the list (view)

this is an example : 
1/Bean :

add this funtion :

```
public List<items> loadList() {
     List<items> Mylist = new ArrayList<tests>();

    //Your code to fill the list 

  return Mylist;

    }
```

2/Servlet :

```
public class ExampleServlet extends HttpServlet {


    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {


                catalog MyObject = new catalog();


       try {
            List<items> list = MyObject.loadList();

        request.setAttribute("recolist", list);

        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("My.jsp");
        view.forward(request, response); 


         } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }


    }}
```

3/ JSP -My.jsp- : 
add this code to your JSP page

```
<c:forEach var="VAR" items="${recolist}">

<li>${VAR./*WHAT YOU WANT*/}</li>                                                           
</c:forEach>
```

Note that VAR is a items object you can call any attribute of the object items for example id , name ...

Answer (score 0):

You can write a method in your bean class (catalog), just like:

```
public String getItemsList()
{
    String printlist = "";
    for(item i:items)//object you want to loop
    {
        printlist = "<li>xxxxxxxxxx</li>";
        ........
    }
    return printlist;
}
```

Then, change `${catalog.items}` to `${catalog.itemsList}` in your jsp page.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Is it respecting MVC?

Comment: I learned this way in my university's course about JSP MVC, I think this is the correct way to do it.

Comment: In older JSP framework, we need to use<jsp:useBean> and <jsp:getProperty> to retrieve bean objects. In JSP2 framework, just use ${xxxx.xxxx}.